# included file variables not accessable in calling file

Tags: php

**Note:** The variable is set in included file, the issue is not an undefined variable, hence the duplicate question is not relevant to my question.
[PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

**Edit:** i just noted my localhost include path is set to C:\xampp\php\PEAR when i did echo get_include_path(); but i don't get error for included file not found rather the variable is undefined.

I have 2 files in `C:/xampp/htdocs/test/` `index.php` `config.php`

Content of index.php:

```
require 'config.php';
echo $name;
```

Content of config.php:

```
$name = 'xyz';
```

And i get `Notice: Undefined variable: name`
Where the `$name = 'xyz'` is in config.php which is included before using the variable.

I have to yet test it on live server. Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: try to get errors using `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`

Comment: @PHPExpert hi, i tried as u suggested. it suppresses the notice and the name is never echoed this way.

Comment: Use `require 'config.php';` instead of `include 'config.php';`. This will throw a fatal error if file is not found.

Comment: @maxhb require/include same result, shows notice. i just notied my localhost include path is set to `C:\xampp\php\PEAR` when i did `echo get_include_path();`

Comment: Use `require './config.php';`

Comment: ^ same notice nothing changed. I think i have to set my include path to be the current directory instead of the one that is in my edit.

Comment: Nope, i just tested. The problem is not with path. The config.php is being include. i made an invalid path and it did gave me file not found error. so the file is being included but the variableis not getting in included scope somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holly Cow.

There was no error in the file.
The php start tag was not correct, it was short tag `<? ?>` instead of `<?php ?>` this was causing the issue.

i'm using php7 on my localhost. but of course t would work on older version of PHP and hosting.

Answer (score 2):

```
    hi i tried your code but i didn't get any error..

    config.php

    <?php
    $name='hello';
    ?>

    index.php

    <?php
    require 'config.php';
    echo $name;
    ?>

include and require both are working
```